# Does MongoDB::execute uses mongos eval() internally?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

The PHP Mongo Driver allows me to execute code in the database.
Does this work in sharded environments? I know, that evaluating code with eval() doesn't work in a sharded environment.

```
$db->execute(
    new MongoCode('SomeFunc(o)', array(
        'o' => array('name' => 'test') 
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no.

Longer answer: `MongoCode` is used for sending JavaScript code to MongoDB in much the same way as if you entered it through Mongo shell. So it's MongoDB's responsibility to run the supplied code - it does not run inside the PHP engine.

UPDATE: I missed that part in your question about sharded environment which quite changes the short answer. ;)

Comment: You have two options - you can fetch the data to one computer and calculate stuff there (recommended, if/while you can get away with it) or you can use mapReduce or similar. Note that MR in MongoDB is (or was, last time I checked) single threaded and can't really compete with Hadoop (which you can use with mongoDB too). But think twice before using MR, it takes a LOT more development time and is slow compared to normal processing. It is only useful for really HUGE amounts of data. My advice would be to start with first option and use MR only when single process doesn't suffice anymore.

Comment: I already implemented your first suggestion in node.js. The problem is, that it is slow with a huge amount of data (i tested with about 100k entries).
So my idea was to move the code from node to mongo as stored procedure and call it from my middleware.

Comment: I have no experience with node.js. That said, 100k entries doesn't sound like much data. Of course it depends on how large each record is and what you are doing with it, but I would try to find the bottlenecks in your implementation. MR will not help you here - it will probably slow things down, not to mention the time you will spend developing for it. To paraphrase Knuth: "premature scaling is the root of all evil". ;)

Comment: I ended up using the new Aggregation Framework of mongodb (introduced in 2.1). It's designed to be fast and works in sharded environments.